# How to correctly reference the User model in a form

Tags: validation, django-models, django-forms

Basically I'm trying to offer a feature for my site where one can register an electric imp(more than one) to their user account. My issue is that my Device model, and by extension my DeviceForm ModelForm uses a ForeignKey to reference the user object. So when I go to register a device it asks for the name of the device, the imp's agent_id, the device type and the user to associate with the account. I think where my is_valid() validation is failing is with how I reference the User model. I don't think its a "valid" input for the user object. Is there a different way to use the User's username to link the device to the correct account?

Models.py:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    agent_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=(
        ("imp", "Electric Imp P3V3"),
    ))
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['name', 'agent_id', 'device_type', 'owner']
    def clean_agent_id(self):
        agent_id = self.cleaned_data['agent_id']
        if Device.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(agent_id=agent_id).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'agent_id "%s" is already in use.' % agent_id)
        return agent_id
```

Views.py:

```
def devices(request):
    devform = DeviceForm(request.POST)
    if devform.is_valid():
        device_obj = devform.save()
        device_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('deviceconfirmation')
    else:
        devform = DeviceForm()
    return render_to_response('courses/devices.html', {'devform': devform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

devices.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ page.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<article>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p id="devicecreate">Register your device to your account:</p>
        <form action="{% url 'courses:deviceconfirmation' %}" id="devform" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
            <p>
                <label for="name">Device Name:</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="agent_id">Agent ID:</label>
                <input id="agent_id" name="agent_id" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="device_type">Imp Type:</label>
                <select name="device_type" form="devform" id="selectbox">
                    <option value="imp">Imp Regular</option>
                    <option value="Electric Imp P3V3">Imp P3V3</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="owner">Device Owner(username):</label>
                <input id="owner" name="owner" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="REGISTER DEVICE" id="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

</article>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py for device confirmation:

```
def deviceconfirmation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            dev = Device.objects.get(agent_id=request.POST['agent_id'])
            return render(request, 'courses/deviceconfirmation.html', {'dev': dev})
        except Device.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('invalidimp')
    else:
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
               url(r'contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
               url(r'login/$', views.login, name='login'),
               url(r'products/$', views.products, name='products'),
               url(r'register/$', views.register, name='register'),
               url(r'register/thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
               url(r'register/inuse/$', views.inuse, name='inuse'),
               url(r'login/accountinfo/$', views.accountinfo, name='accountinfo'),
               url(r'devices/$', views.devices, name='devices'),
               url(r'devices/deviceconfirmation/$', views.deviceconfirmation, name='deviceconfirmation'),
               url(r'devices/deviceconfirmation/invalidimp/$', views.invalidimp, name='invalidimp'),
]
```

Comment: I guess the user need to be logged in to register the device? Also, can the user register the device to someone else or to himself only?

Comment: at the moment it's just one logged in user who can have multiple devices. I might change it to multiple users later but I just want to get it working first.

Comment: Can you post your URLs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For when the logged in user adds a device to himself only: You can pass the current user as owner to the Form when you post. You don't need the owner initially in the form if not posting. In the form, override the save method and pass the owner before saving the device instance.

--

**update** based on comments:

- amends to url for deviceconfirmation and view; url now accepts the device id. See bellow code updated
- see also the template updated info

View (assuming def devices is used for both get and post):

```
def devices(request):
    if request.method == 'POST":
        devform = DeviceForm(request.POST, owner=request.user)
        if devform.is_valid():
            dev = devform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('deviceconfirmation', kwargs={'device_id': dev.id}))
        else:
            return render_to_response('courses/devices.html', {'devform': devform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        devform = DeviceForm()
    return render_to_response('courses/devices.html', {'devform': devform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

View deviceconfirmation:

```
def deviceconfirmation(request, device_id=None):
        try:
            dev = Device.objects.get(id=device_id)
            return render(request, 'courses/deviceconfirmation.html', {'dev': dev})
        except Device.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('invalidimp')
```

Form:

```
class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['name', 'agent_id', 'device_type']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        owner = kwargs.pop('owner', None)
        super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.owner = owner;

    def clean_agent_id(self):
        agent_id = self.cleaned_data['agent_id']
        if Device.objects.filter(agent_id=agent_id).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'agent_id "%s" is already in use.' % agent_id)
        return agent_id

    def save(self, commit=True):
        device = super(DeviceForm, self).save(commit=False)
        device.owner = self.owner
        if commit:
            device.save()
        return device
```

Template:

- delete the form action url in the template -> when you post, it will go to the same view from which you did the get (which is the `devices` view) ; `<form action="" .....>`
- remove owner form field - to display current owner username, just use
  `{{request.user.username}}`

URL:

```
url(r'devices/deviceconfirmation/(?P<device_id>\S+)/$', views.deviceconfirmation, name='deviceconfirmation'),
```

Comment: the only question I have is what is MyForm? it's not defined for me and it's bringing up an error

Comment: Ah, it should have been the name of the form. My mistake, updated the answer

Comment: I'm still running into the issue of it redirecting to the 'invalid imp' page I created if the Imp's agent_id is already in use. I don't think it should be doing this because my courses_device collection has 0 docs in it. I edited the question and included the device confirmation view at the bottom

Comment: updated answer. let me know if it does what you want or have any questions

Comment: everything is looking good except that I'm getting an error that "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'owner'" I tried adding the word 'owner' to the fields in my DeviceForm but no cigar

Comment: hmm strange. added super as first in the init. try that

Comment: I don't think I can use owner as an argument for my DeviceForm. The error arises from line 54 in views.py "devform = DeviceForm(request.POST, owner=request.user)" and then line 114 in models.py "super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)"

Comment: i removed the owner=request.user from my DeviceForm comment and it is now passing the code but I'm getting a new database error: "AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'pavlecoric' instead)." However, all the stack overflow questions about this autodialed error were for u'1' when the person didn't have the siteid entered correctly but i do have the site id entered correctly. I tried making my username the primary key for the device class and still no cigar, I'm going to keep troubleshooting but this might need to be a separate question

Comment: I think I know what the problem might be. Use in the init of the form kwargs.pop instead of kwargs.get. That way, owner will be removed from kwargs before being passed to super. Updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85433/discussion-between-bogdig-and-user3393571).

Comment: also I don't think you were having a self.instance when cleaning the agent_id. updated the query to check if a device that has that agent_id exists